# match hebrew character at word boundary via regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I'm able to match and highlight this Hebrew letter in JS:

```
var myText = $('#text').html();
var myHilite = myText.replace(/(\u05D0+)/g,"<span class='highlight'>$1</span>");
$('#text').html(myHilite);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/mf9Su/2/)

but can't highlight a word containing that letter at a word boundary:

```
/(\u05D0)\b/g
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/mf9Su/3/)

I know that JS is [bad at regex with Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590098/javascript-regexp-word-boundaries-unicode-characters) (and server side is preferred), but I also know that I'm bad at regex. Is this a limit in JS or an error in my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't read Hebrew... does this regex do what you want?

```
/(\S*[\u05D0]+\S*)/g
```

Your first regex, `/(\u05D0+)/g` matches on only the character you are interested in.

Your second regex, `/(\u05D0)\b/g`, matches only when the character you are interested in is the last-only (or last-repeated) character before a word boundary...so that doesn't won't match that character in the beginning or middle of a word.

EDIT:

Look at this anwer

[utf-8 word boundary regex in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881445/utf-8-word-boundary-regex-in-javascript)

Using the info from that answer, I come up with this regex, is this correct?

`/([\u05D0])(?=\s|$)/g`

Comment: seems to match any word containing that letter at any position: http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/mf9Su/4/ -- but basically you're trying to use \S instead of \b ?

Comment: do you want to match that character only as the last character in a word, or do you also want to match it at the beginning of a word boundary?

Comment: I think only as the last character in a word. I'm not clear on the difference (again I suck at regex).

Comment: re:edit - that matches the letter at the location I want. What I'm hoping for is to match every word in which that letter is at that location .. does that make sense? i'll check out that q&a ..

Comment: As `\u05D0` is considered a non-word character there will not be a word boundary if it is followed by another non-word character such as a space. For there to be a word boundary after `\u05D0`, it would have to be followed by a word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the following regexp which uses all cases of a word in a sentence:

```
/^u05D0\s|\u05D0$|\u05D0\s|^\u05D0$/
```

it actually uses 4 regexps with the OR operator ('|').

1. Either the string starts with your exact word followed by a space
2. OR your string has space + your word + space
3. OR your string ends with space + your word
4. OR your string is the exact word only.