# Text matching using regex matches words with no space only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, arabic

I need to match keywords and replace those keywords with `<a />` html or `<span></span>` tags. Script which i am working on match only  single words with no space if i use following regex, `\w`

```
text = text.replace(
            /([\u0600-\u06ff\w]+)([^\u0600-\u06ff]+)()?/g,
        replacer);
```

and if i use following regex with `\s` option then it match all words wrapped withing ASCII such as `,` `"`, `'` etc.. in fiddle example you will notice it will match all keywords for this from the first paragraphs and which a separated by `,`

```
   text2 = text2.replace(
        /([\u0600-\u06ff\s]+)([^\u0600-\u06ff]+)()?/g,
    replacer);
```

How can i modify this script so that it works with combinations and match only exact words. I have been working with for few days i tried few option also but non seems to be working, i tried highlight plugin that also had its own issue with arabic.
question raised for highlight plugin also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533793/highlighting-of-text-breaks-when-for-either-english-or-arabic

Regex Matching : http://jsfiddle.net/u3k01bfw/13/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881445/utf-8-word-boundary-regex-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that changing `()?` to `(?=\s|$)` (that will limit the matches up to a space or a string end) can fix your issue:

```
text = text.replace(
        /([\u0600-\u06ff\w]+)([^\u0600-\u06ff]+)(?=\s|$)/g,
    replacer);

text2 = text2.replace(
        /([\u0600-\u06ff\s]+)([^\u0600-\u06ff]+)(?=\s|$)/g,
    replacer);
```

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/u3k01bfw/17/.