# Javascript Regex Lookbehind Alternative

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to catch word with non-space.

```
var paragraphy="Apple banana kişiler ki örnek foo.";
var word="kişiler"; 
var regex = new RegExp("(?:[\\s>]|^)("+word+")(?=[.,;?!]?(?:[<\\s])|$)", "gi");
console.log(paragraphy.match);
```

This prints: [" kişiler"] but I want this result: ["kişiler"]
I must use Positive Lookbehind but it is not supported in JavaScript. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: why use positive lookbehind??why not word boundary?use `\bword\b`..

and where are you even using lookbehind in regex?

Comment: your question is not at all clear..rephrase it

Comment: @rock321987 I have this characters: "şöüğçıİ" so word boundary not catch if the word has this characters.

Comment: This sample:
 var regex=new RegExp("(?<=[\\s>]|^)("+word+")(?=[.,;?!]?(?:[<\\s])|$)", "gi"); @rock321987

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881445/utf-8-word-boundary-regex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use word boundaries with unicode characters, let's match the spaces but group the word to retrieve it :

```
(?:^|\s)(<your word>)(?:\s|$)
```

After a match, group 1 should be the expected word.

For instance :

```
var regex = /(?:^|\s)(kişiler)(?:\s|$)/
var paragraphy="Apple banana kişiler ki örnek foo."
paragraphy.match(regex)[1]
> "kişiler"
```

Comment: thanks but result: [" kişiler "] why catch with space?

Comment: because as you said there's no lookbehind, so you must catch everything you want to check and then only retrieve the interesting part thanks to grouping. `paragraphy.match(regex)[1]` in my example is retrieving group 1 of the match, which corresponds to your specified word.

Comment: My English is not good enough, that's why you find it difficult to express myself and understand. even so your solution is work Thank yo very much.

Answer (score 1):

*JS Demo*

```js
var paragraphy="Apple ba kişiler nana ki örnek foo.";
var word="kişiler"; 
var regex = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)("+word+")(?=\\s|$)", "gi");
var m = regex.exec(paragraphy);
document.writeln(m[1]);
```