# C++ and JS RegEx equivalent of \p{L}

Tags: javascript, java, c++, regex

I need to match all unicode characters in Email Addresses. I could do this validation in Java using \p{L}. Is there any \p{L} equivalent in JS and C++ ?

If not which is the best reliable open source library which provides this capability in C++ and JavaScript ?

Comment: *JS **and** C++* ?

Comment: You can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470212/match-any-non-word-character-excluding-diacritics/37471102#37471102). In C++, you will need to use `wregex`, remember? :) Why haven't you accepted the previous answer?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: Default flavor `std::regex` uses is ECMAScript. Although it is a bit different from JS implementation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks :)

Comment: @Wiktor No need for `wregex` at all, `std::regex` can handle Unicode encodings just fine.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Then post an example and let me know how to use it in the Visual Studio 2012 C++ project.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew VS2012? No idea. You didn’t mention that you were on a non-compliant compiler. A *compliant* compiler handles it.

Comment: @vijin: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Visual Studio 2010 !

Comment: Did you test the regex I linked to? Does it work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew To use wregex I need to convert my basic string to wstring. What is the easy way for that ? I think  the following code will work for only when the basic string consists of ASCII charcters --------------std::wstring wstring(str.begin(), str.end());

Comment: You should declare the pattern with `L"patternhere"`.

Comment: >std::wstring ws(L"test");
    std::string str(ws.begin(), ws.end());
    std::wsmatch wm;std::wregex reg(L"[\\\\p{L]+");
    if (regex_match(ws.cbegin(), ws.cend(), wm, reg))
    {
     return true;
    }
    else
    {
     return false;
    }  '  This is returning false always !

Comment: You seem to forget that ECMAScript does not support Unicode category classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115440/discussion-between-vijin-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: I tried your suggestion in JS. 
var XRegExp = require('xregexp');
this.REGEXP_EMAIL_INT_LOCAL_PART  = XRegExp('^[//p{L}0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~\.-]*$'); 
But this shows error : require is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMAScript, as well as all other flavors supported by the `std::regex`, does not support Unicode properties (Unicode category classes).

As a workaround, use [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0_b1/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/non_std_strings/icu.html) in C++.

In Boost, declare the regex as follows:

```
boost::wregex reg(L"^\\p{L}+$");
```

Note that `^\p{L}+$` matches 1+ letter strings only.

In ECMAScript used in JavaScript in modern browsers, you can use

```js
var str = "bębnić";
var regex = /^\p{L}+$/u;
console.log(regex.test(str));
```

An [XRegExp based solution](http://xregexp.com/) in JavaScript for older browsers (like Safari):

```js
var str = "bębnić";
regex = XRegExp('^\\p{L}+$');
console.log(regex.test(str));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```