# Unicode properties and Firefox JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, unicode

Here is how it works in Chromium:

```
> letter = "\\p{L}"
< "\p{L}"
> reg = RegExp( letter, "gu" )
< /\p{L}/gu
> reg.test("é")
< true
> reg.test("&")
< false
```

In Firefox I get an error:

```
>  letter = "\\p{L}"
< "\\p{L}"
> reg = RegExp( letter, "gu" )
> SyntaxError: invalid identity escape in regular expression
```

So is there a way to make it work in Firefox?

Comment: I don't think Firefox supports those yet.

Comment: @Pointy It's a pity. :( Is there anything known about when it will be supported?

Comment: Use http://xregexp.com/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunately, Firefox haven't implemented lookbehind yet, so even with `xregexp` it's impossible to imitate unicode `\b`.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky That is a different question already, but there are answers on SO. You may either use whitespace boundaries as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881445), or use XRegExp to build [custom Unicode-aware word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37471102/3832970).