# I can't match with this Regular Expression without look behind, and I don't know How

Tags: javascript, regex, text, ecmascript-6

I am using regular expressions to create a simple JavaScript application. I've looked at some answers here from the community, and unfortunately I'm still unable to create a regular expression that suits **my specific case**. I apologize, but I have no mastery over regular expressions.

I wish I could solve my problem without using a reverse function, or any utility function if possible. If this can only be solved with one, then that's fine, there's nothing to be done.

### THE PROBLEM

Consider the following text (it's in portuguese, Brazil, so accented characters need to be considered, like Álvares, Ligações, América, etc.):

```
O Brasil é um país com muitos brasileiros. Alguns dizem Abrasil, outros nem tanto.
```

What I seek:

```
"Brasil" true // Desired result
" Brasil" false
"brasil"eiros false
A"brasil" false
```

The regular expression currently used (**not correct**):

```
([^\w|^\u0080-\u00FF])(Brasil)(?![\w|\u0080-\u00FF])
```

The part of the expression I'm having trouble with:

```
 ([^\w|^\u0080-\u00FF])
```

The (**wrong**) result I am getting at the moment:

```
" Brasil" // I just want "Brasil"
```

### Bibliography

- [javascript regex - look behind alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative)
- [utf-8 word boundary regex in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881445/utf-8-word-boundary-regex-in-javascript)
- [Javascript: negative lookbehind equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Even accepted, [from what I could see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434875/2910546), look behind is not yet widely implemented.

Comment: What exactly do you need ? filter the sentence ? Sum up the number of occurrences in the sentence ?

Comment: @user2541537 I want to be able to search for a term that is not within words. It can be written at the beginning, middle, and end of a sentence. I want to find only Brasil, without finding other words that have Brasil. Also, I don't want to match " Brasil" or "Brasil " or " Brasil ". Why? Because the found word will be replaced later, and I don't want to cut the white space, but just the word.

Comment: Don't worry about the leading character, just replace it (group 1) back with whatever is being replaced by Brazil. Example:  replace `([^\w\u0080-\u00FF]|^)(Brasil)(?![\w\u0080-\u00FF])` with `$1Spain` See https://regex101.com/r/qU13FJ/1